How can I call Windows auth form similarly to the Chrome?
I want to get the Windows authorization form like a Chrome password manager:
Windows authorization form using in Chrome
Is there a ready-made solution with source code?
I'm prefer to use C# and .NET, but alternatives are considered.

Assuming you're using Blazor, you can implement services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate(); There are a few other things that need to be setup in IIS, but you can find those in the MS docs
